# What is the best way to implement a threshold into a hash?

Tags: c++, hash, counting

I want to implement the following in C++:

1. Hash X(ballpark figure: 1 digit millions) 64 Bit Integers
2. Output the elements with occurrence >= Y (user specified) to a binary file

Right now, the code hashes & outputs every element and does not regard low occurrencies.

The obvious solution would be to refactor the code in a way that it hashes not only an integer but a struct. This contains the integer and a counter, which is then checked for being >=Y before outputting the elements into the binary file.
The bottomline is that the memory footprint would increase by X*size_of(counter).

Is there any more sophisticated way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: dear barGer, please read how to post a question before posting it. have a nice stying here in stackoverflow

Comment: dear No Idea For Name, is the question too subjective? thanks for your input.

Comment: If you show me "the code that hashes and outputs every element", I'll show you how to get what you want.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you don’t get a satisfying answer here.

Comment: You can store and sort the data (requires about 8MB) and then in one pass over the array you can find which values occur at least Y times and output them. In other words - are you sure you need a hash table?